# T-SQL - execute procedure individual for each row of select statement needs cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cursor, procedure

I got a table rules with dynamic sql statements in it. With a procedure a specific rule (calculation) can be applied on a table. But now i want to apply all rules (from a select) on that table. Is there any way of doing this without using cursors?
First i tried to use functions. But those doesn't let me execute dynamic sql. So i ended up with procedures and cursors.

Comment: If I understand your question, you're wanting to execute a stored procedure for each result from a query?  If so, yes, that must be done with a cursor (at least, as far as I'm aware).

Comment: Right, that is the problem. I hope to find a faster solution to speed things up, as those procedures will be executed quite often.

Comment: You can build one dynamic `T-SQL` statement which contains all rules and procedure and execute it. Could you give more details? What you have - table name, procedure and some rule (input parameters)?

Comment: There just isn't anywhere near enough information here to provide a real answer. Perhaps you can change the procedure to receive a table valued parameter instead of a single rule. perhaps you can change something else. As it sits right now this is just too vague to provide a real answer. But yes...I am sure that a set based solution could be derived for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

From what i suspect, you have some text to a rules table e.g. RuleID = 1, Rule = '(field1*field2)+field3'. So you resort to dynamic sql to build a statement actually apply the rule. Fair enough, since there is nothing else you can do with that text. This way yes, you probably have to resort to cursor and build sql + execute at every row.
Another workaround if rules are not many and not user defined would be to convert the rule to actual statement and apply with a join if enabled. The above example would be like:

```
SELECT 
...
,CASE WHEN RuleID = 1 THEN (field1*field2)+field3 ELSE NULL END AS Rule1Result
FROM mytable JOIN rulestable ...
```